# Find $P(B^2 \ge 4 A C)$ where $A,B,C$ are uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $A,B,C$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$. Then, I want to find the probability that $B^2 \ge 4 ~A\cdot C$

**Attempt:** The following argument is likely to have some error but I am not able find out, what exactly:

Because $A,B,C$ are independent random variables, thus, $f_{A,B,C} (A = a,B = b, C = c) = f_A(a)~ f_B(b)~ f_C(c)$. Thus:

$f_{A,B,C} (A = a,B = b, C = c) =  \begin{cases} 
      1 & 0\leq a,b,c \le1 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}
$

Now, the required probability is $$\int \int_{\dfrac{B^2}{4} \ge AC} \int~f_{A,B,C} (a,b,c)~ da ~db ~dc$$

$$ = \int_{a=0}^{a=1} \int_{b=0}^{b=1} \int_{c=0}^{c={\frac{b^2}{4a}}} 1 \cdot dc~ db~da$$

**Solving this integral gives an unexpected result.**

Could someone please tell me where could I be makingg a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper bound $c = \frac{b^2}{4a}$ could be bigger than $1$; however, $c$ should only range from $0$ to $1$. So the integral should be
$$
   \int_{a=0}^{a=1} \int_{b=0}^{b=1} \int_{c=0}^{c=\min\{\frac{b^2}{4a},1\}}1\,dc\,db\,da
$$
which gives the right answer, eventually.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually I got $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{12 a} \, da$ and  it fails to converge.

Comment: @Raffaele That's what you get if you ignore the upper bound on $c$.

Comment: I got it! Thank you, now it gives $\frac{1}{36} (5+6 \log 2)\approx 0.2544$ which is consistent with the simulations.